# Will Realtek audio manager detect my USB microphone if i use a convert USB female to jack 3.5 male?

Tags: audio, microphone, realtek-hd-audio

So i now using a razer seiren mini which has usb head plug into my PC

I find out that realtek audio manager can only detect jack 3.5 devices plug in (Is this true?)

Will Realtek audio manager will finally detect if i use 3.5mm Male AUX Audio Plug Jack To USB 2.0 Female?

[3.5mm Male AUX Audio Plug Jack To USB 2.0 Female](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Qhf.png)

Comment: That looks very sketchy. Where did you find that product?

Comment: Why not simply use the USB plug?  Then the headset is its own audio device having nothing to do with Reaktek.  Why do you want mediocre Realtek software to be part of this when there is no need?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It seem that realtek has a echo cancellation function. In the past i have the microphone and speaker both have a jack 3.5 plugin, both detect by realtek and the echo cancellation work perfectly. Now the speaker remain but i use a microphone usb plug in which is very anonoying echo when talking to my friend through any platform

Comment: @gronostaj its a razer seiren mini microphone

Comment: If you werent "playing through" with the mic, you wouldn't need echo cancellation.  Do you really need to "Listen to this device" in the settings?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas unfortunately i dont check "Listen to this device" in the settings but it still echo

Comment: I'm asking about the adapter (and I'm 99% sure it won't work)

Comment: @gronostaj yeah im highly doubt it will work or possibe too so im just asking. Thank you